# mysqli_query gives empty value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Im creating a login system for my website.
I got the problem that my mysqli_query is empty:

The code: `$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q); returns empty.`

I think the problem is in the sql language that i pass it:

```
$q = "SELECT userid, fname, lname FROM User WHERE email='$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p')";
```

If i execute the sql above with the data that im actually is fetching from the form then i will get the result Im looking for. So i think its the php and sql combined that got an error.

```
if(empty($errors)){
    $q = "SELECT userid, fname, lname FROM User WHERE email='$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p')";

    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    //Check for right data
    $errors[] = $e;
    $errors[] = $p;
    //Check if connection is up
    if($dbc != null){
        $errors[] = "Connection up";
    }
    //Check query
    if(is_null($r)){
        $errors[] = "Query is null";
    }
    //Check query for being empty
    if(empty($r)){
        $errors[] = "Its empty";
    }
    if( mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return array(true, $row);
    }else{
        $errors[] = "Email address and password not found.";
    }
    return array(false, $errors);

}
```

Comment: Is the query resulting in an error, or simply not finding any results?  If the latter, what is the actual runtime query being performed and does it match any results in the database?  If you perform the same query manually against the database, are the results different?

Comment: Its when calling if(empty($r)){ $error[] = "Its empty";} that it says $r is empty.
If i take the sql statement and execute it in the database then i get the results i want.

Comment: If "empty" means there was an error, check the database for errors.  If "empty" means there were no matching results, test the query manually against the database and see what you find.  If no record in the table matches the criteria in the `WHERE` clause then no results will be returned.  (Note: Your logos after that is broken.  If the number of results is greater than one that would hardly mean that the email and password aren't found...)

Comment: Could you maybe make an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
if(empty($errors)){
    $p = sha1($p);
    $q = "SELECT userid, fname, lname FROM User WHERE email = '$e' AND pass = '$p'";

    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    if(!$r){
        die(mysqli_error($dbc));
    }

    //Check for right data
    $errors[] = $e;
    $errors[] = $p;
    //Check if connection is up
    if($dbc != null){
        $errors[] = "Connection up";
    }
    //Check query
    if(is_null($r)){
        $errors[] = "Query is null";
    }
    //Check query for being empty
    if(empty($r)){
        $errors[] = "Its empty";
    }
    if( mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
        return array(true, $row['userid'], $row['fname'], $row['lname']);
    }else{
        $errors[] = "Email address and password not found.";
    }
    return array_merge(array(true), $errors);
}
```

Comment: Check by `mysqli_error($dbc)` as i updated what is going wrong!